# Prevent downloading from direct download link from site other then my using PHP

Tags: php, file, download

I have file hosted on my server like www.myname.com/mp3/file-1.mp3.

I want that only visitors of my site can download the files. If any one share  the url on other sites the download should not start.

How can I achieve this using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I give you some stept:

1. Create a PHP file
2. Let the user authenticate on this page
3. When login is succesfull, use headers to force the download with your provided link (there are enough tutorials for this)

With this approach the real link is never exposed, and the user has to authenticate to get the file. Im not sure if the original link can be read out in the browser, but there must be an option for it. Or host your file on a not accessible part of your site (often the parent of the public_html folder).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by .htaccess.

create .htaccess and enter following code.

```
<files file-1.mp3>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```